# Capturing groups using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a url like

```
/url?q=https://someline.com&sa=someotherdata
```

I tried using

(https[^&])

to extract `https://someline.com`. This does not work. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Use quantifier `+` to repeat the match for one or more characters

```
(https[^&]+)
```

- `[^&]+` Matches anything other than `&` one or more times ( `+` ensures this repeating)

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sP4hT8/1)

Answer (score 0):

The expression just needs a quantifier

```
(https[^&]+)
```

And it will work. The character range [...] is a single character expression and it will match exactly one character, if possible. Adding the quantifier "+" causes the previous expression to be matched one or more times.